# Showing a function is constant using Schwarz reflection prinbiple

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to solve the following problem: Let $f$ be a function non-vanishing and holomorphic on the unit disk $\mathbb{D}$, continuous on its closure $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$ and such that $|f(z)| \equiv 1$ along $\partial \mathbb{D}$. Show that $f$ is constant on $\overline{\mathbb{D}}$. A hint given for this problem says to use Schwarz reflection principle to get the conclusion, but I really don't see how to do it. Can anybody help me out?

Thanks!

Comment: @saulspatz $f(z) = z$ is not non-vanishing.

Comment: @PaulFrost I overlooked that, thanks.